# Pig script filter a file getting ERROR

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

I am new to pig. I'm trying to filter the text file and store it in hbase. Here is the sample input file

**sample.txt**

```
{"pattern":"google_1473491793_265244074740","tweets":[{"tweet::created_at":"18:47:31 ","tweet::id":"252479809098223616","tweet::user_id":"450990391","tweet::text":"rt @joey7barton: ..give a google about whether the americans wins a ryder cup. i mean surely he has slightly more important matters. #fami ..."}]}
{"pattern":"facebook_1473491793_265244074740","tweets":[{"tweet::created_at":"11:33:16 ","tweet::id":"252370526411051008","tweet::user_id":"845912316","tweet::text":"@maarionymcmb facebook mere ta dit tu va resté chez toi dnc tu restes !"}]}
```

**Script:**

```
data = load 'sample.txt' using JsonLoader('pattern:chararray, tweets:  bag {t1:tuple(tweet::created_at: chararray,tweet::id: chararray,tweet::user_id: chararray,tweet::text: chararray)}');
A = FILTER data BY pattern == 'google_*';
grouped = foreach (group A by pattern){tweets1 = foreach data generate tweets.(created_at),tweets.(id),tweets.(user_id),tweets.(text); generate group as pattern1,tweets1;}
```

But I got this error when run grouped:

```
2016-09-10 13:38:52,995 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse: <line 41, column 57> expression is not a project expression: (Name: ScalarExpression) Type: null Uid: null)
```

Comment: 1. What output do you expect to get? Is it (pattern,created_at,id,user_id,text), that is a pattern + single tweet per record?
2. The filter is messed up; to have only google_* pattern use

A = FILTER data BY pattern matches 'google_.*'; It's not the cause of your exception though.

Comment: thanks for your reply  @patrungel.the expected output as (pattern)({complete all the tweets}.can you please suggest me how can i get this.

Answer (score 0):

In the nested you can't reference the 'tweets', you need to the 'A'. See my example below.

```
grouped = FOREACH (GROUP A BY pattern) {
GENERATE groups AS pattern, A.created_at, A.id, A.user_id, A.text;
};
```

Comment: For that to work with the given input, tweets from relation `A` should first be flat-mapped since currently it's a bag of tweets though each record from the given dataset has only one entry in the bag.

Comment: Yes, a good catch. I did not pay enough attention to input data format.